# How to access cell array from an index i to the end

Tags: matlab, matrix, cell, cell-array

```
[~,~,rawdata] = xlsread('somefile');
```

`rawdata` is a cell array of 1311 x 14 cells. I want to access from second row to last row for a specified column.

like `rawdata{2:,ith col}` but it gives an error.

The end purpose I am trying to solve is to find `NaN` count for each column of a 2-D cell array imported from excel of heterogeneous format.

Comment: Can you share the error ? Did you test rawdata{2:end,ith col}? you have to write 'end'

Comment: >> rawdata(2:,:) . On executing this , error is "Error: Expression or statement is incorrect--possibly unbalanced (, {, or [" showing a marker | at comma symbol in expression executed.

Comment: `2:` is not valid Matlab syntax, you need to specify where the vector should end. Also, are you using `{` and `}` like in the question, or `(` and `)` like in your comment?

Comment: @David: Is there a symbol to specify till the end

Comment: @David: Both { and ( give same error. Also, I am confused in when to use ( and when to use {

Comment: Maybe read a basic Matlab introduction. `(` is for arrays and function, `{` is for cell arrays. `2:end` gives you the second to the last element of a row/column of an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`rawdata(2:end,ith_col)` should work, as discussed in the comments.

Use `end` to refer to the last character in a matrix or array.

Use `()` to refer to a block of elements in an array or matrix. As an element of a matrix is conceptually a 1x1 matrix, `myMatrix(1,3)` gets the third element in the first row.

Use `{}` to extract a single element from an array. For example:

```
myCell = {'test','hello_world',56,[1;2;3]};
disp(myCell(1))
disp(myCell{1})
```

Would first print the 1x1 cell {'test'} (appears `'test'` in the command window) and then the string 'test' (appears `test`)

Answer (score 0):

To obtain the **number of cells that equal `NaN` in each column**, you can use

```
result = sum(cellfun(@(n) isequalwithequalnans(n,NaN), rawdata), 1);
```

For example,

```
rawdata = { 'aa', NaN;
            2,    NaN;
            NaN,    3 };
```

produces

```
result =
     1     2
```

---

If all of your cells **contain either `NaN` or a number** (so no strings etc), you can use the simpler

```
result = sum(cellfun(@isnan, rawdata), 1);
```

For example,

```
rawdata = { 1,   NaN,   3;
            2,   NaN, NaN;
            NaN,   7,   4 };
```

gives

```
result =
     1     2     1
```